# Multidimensional NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

In my project I use 2 NSMutableArrays. The values in each array related to each other by the array element number. I need to find a way how to remove duplicated values from the first array and remove related value from the second array.

Comment: That would be / is an excellent interview puzzle.  You can probably find the answer by searching in interview prep guides.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you :) I was thinking to use NSMutableDictionary to store arrays. However I don't know how to remove duplicates from it? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you make an NSMutableDictionary to hold the values and indexes from your *first* array. Use the values from the array as the keys for the dictionary and the NSNumber representations of the index values from the array as the values in the dictionary.

Iterate through the first array, adding key/value pairs to the dictionary.  You can test the existing dictionary keys to see if this value has already been added.  If it has, you don't add it, and if I understand correctly, you can remove the corresponding entry from your *second* array.